# What does a .NET Core Self-Contained Deployment Without a Runtime Defined Produce?

Tags: .net-core

I have a project that has a csproj similar to:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netcoreapp1.1</TargetFrameworks>
  <AssemblyName>ConsoleApp</AssemblyName>
  <PackageId>ConsoleApp</PackageId>
  <Version>1.0.0.1</Version>
  <RootNamespace>ConsoleApp</RootNamespace>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64;android.21;android.21-arm64;osx.10.12;rhel7.4;centos.7-x64;debian.8-x64;ubuntu.16.10-x64;fedora.26-x64;opensuse.42.1-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(_ShortFrameworkIdentifier)' == 'netstandard' ">   
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime.CoreCLR" Version="1.1.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPolicy" Version="1.1.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

If I run `dotnet publish -c Release -f netstandard2.0` and don't specify a runtime I get output at: `..\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\publish` that has what looks like it would be a self-contained deployment, except the main "executable" is a dll (as opposed to if I defined a runtime I'd get an exe or a file with no extension) as well as a folder called runtimes, which looks like it has some runtime specific libraries for different OS's like unix, osx, rhel, like System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, etc.

What does this type of publishing actually produce? Is this set of of files in any way useful?

Comment: You can run it with dotnet.  Compare to the way you'd run a Java or Python program.

Comment: What is the rational of building a console app that targets .NET Standard 2.0? Clearly you don't have to.

Comment: @LexLi, are you asking why use .netstandard2.0 vs .netstandard1.6 or vs netcoreapp1.1?

Comment: For .NET Core console apps, you should only target netcoreappXX. Why do you use netstandardXX?

Comment: To use the "small footprint" SCD deployment model, you target netstandardx.x, as shown in Microsoft's documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli#small-footprint-self-contained-deployment

Answer (score 0):

If you use upcoming tooling for `netstandard2.0` this will not generate a usable deployment because for 2.0, all packages (`NETStandard.Library` and `Microsoft.NETCore.App`) are flat and not reference individual components.

The reason you could get a "small footprint" application this way when targeting `netstandard1.6` was mainly due to a side effect of the way `Microsoft.NETCore.App` was constructed (targeting a netstandard version and the individual components bringing in implementations for runtimes).

The logic for publishing the main entry point is tied to the components resolved from the components. For netcoreapp1.*, a `dotnet.exe`/ `dotnet` executable is renamed, for 2.0+ it is `apphost.exe`/`apphost` which is renamed and the name of the `dll` file embedded.

Comment: I'm totally capable of creating a "small footprint" SCD using `dotnet publish -c Release -f netstandard2.0 -r win10-x64` as well as a framework dependent deployment with netcoreapp. That all works just fine, I was just wondering what the purpose of supporting that command without using `-r myruntime` was when the output type was defined as an exe not a library? The resulting set of files don't run using `dotnet myapp` and results in an error: A fatal error was encountered. The library 'hostpolicy.dll' required to execute the application was not found in '..\bin\Release\netstandard2.0\publish'.

Comment: do you use released tooling or a 2.0 preview that knows about `netstandard2.0`? The current (1.0.3 or today's 1.0.4) CLIs will fall back to netstandard1.6 behaviour for those packages..

Comment: I'm using 1.0.3. If I change the csproj to netstandard1.6, the output in the `..\bin\Release\netstandard1.6\publish` directory is exactly the same, which is what you said it would do. But I'm still not sure what that collection of files "represents" or if they're just essentially useless and we shouldn't be able to run a `dotnet publish -f netstandardx.x` without a runtime defined when the output type is set to `exe`?